# undelegating events handlers on 'lose-focus'

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to phrase this as clearly as I can.

I have a view that shows a form.  I am tying an event handler to the submit button like this:

```
events: {
    'click #bsubmit': 'save'
}
```

In the save function, on success, I take care to undelegateEvents() before I navigate away:

```
...
that.undelegateEvents();
window.router.navigate('#/home');
...
```

So if someone comes to this page, submits the page and goes to (actually: is sent back) the home page, is all good.

However, there is also a 'home' link shown there, which part of the top level template.  It is specified like this:

```
<a href="#/home">Home</a>
```

So if someone comes to this page, clicks on the home link, and (from there) returns to this page, the event is mapped a second time.  Now when someone submits the form, it gets submitted two times.

Given that I have many views, and the navigation away can happen in many ways, what is the common pattern to undelegateEvents when navigation happens at a higher (uncontrollable) manner?  Or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Do you want to call that.undelegateEvents() each time you want to navigate to the home page?

Comment: I am looking for a way to call undelegateEvents() from any view whenever there is an 'unexpected' navigation.  From the home, it would be possible open view1, view2, etc.  and from each of those views it would be possible to return to the home page.  at each time we need to undelegateEvents (from the view) OR find some other way to undelegate the event (from outside the view).  That is why 'lose-focus' in the title.

Comment: Maybe you can use Backbone.Events to fire an event whenever the 'unexpected' condition occurs and have a callback listen to the event. In the callback, you can undelegateEvents()

Comment: how do I write this 'callback' and how do I call it from every view.

Comment: You can have any object firing this event. Events need not be part of views. I guess you can undelegate the events from outside the view.

Comment: Your router should `v.remove()` the current view, `v`, and then create the new view to replace it. And all your views should have `remove` methods to unbind any model/collection events; if a view doesn't bind to any model or collection events, then the default `remove` is probably sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you don't need to undelegate events. Simply remove your form from the DOM with `$('el').remove()`, javascript events will automatically be removed

The best solution would be to have a `HomepageView` and `FormView` each in the same container (let say `.container`).

Example of a complete scenario:

- User go to #homepage, we instanciate a `HomepageView` and render it in `.container`
- User go to #form, we instanciate a `FormView` and render it in `.container`
- User go to #homepage, we instanciate a `HomepageView` and render it in `.container`
- ...etc, etc

So, each time the user navigate to a new route the previous view is replaced by the new one.

As the previous view HTML no longer belongs to the DOM you don't need anymore to undelegate events.

Of course the `.container` element do not belongs to our views, each view has it's own element rendered inside the `.container` element.

Read this [blog post](http://jules.boussekeyt.org/2012/memory-free-backbone-router.html) for more informations.

Comment: this answer showed the way.  the additional thing was that I was using el in the view and not tagName and the id in the el was part of the static outer template.  so removing the view removed the id itself and it then nothing else worked (because of the way I wrote my code).. i replaced the el with tagName and made the render function append to the #id.  this is working. i am still probably doing things inefficiently, but this answer is close enough. accepted.